# Trying to create new flutter project

Tags: terminal

Hi I am new to fluter just starting out. I am trying to create my first flutter app with these steps:
Create and run a simple Flutter app

To create your first Flutter app and test your setup, follow these steps:

Create a new Flutter app by running the following from the command line:

content_copy
flutter create my_app
A my_app directory is created, containing Flutter’s starter app. Enter this directory:

content_copy
cd my_app
To launch the app in the Simulator, ensure that the Simulator is running and enter:

content_copy
flutter run

when I start the first step I get this error message.
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for sysctl.
(goes down to 42 different ones.)

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: What does "goes down to 42 different ones" mean?

Comment: sorry I mean its got 42 lines of errors

Comment: I could send a screen shot if that would help?